# Как создать свой собственный ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, синхронизация

У Рихтера в разделе гибридных конструкций синхронизации есть пример как можно сделать свою не сложную. А вот как сделать ReaderWriterLockSlim осталось под вопросом, так как там есть зависимость пишущих и читающих тредов. Пока сложно представляю как это можно организовать красиво. Там даже есть ссылка на код, но она не работает.

Comment: [как-то так](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs)

Comment: Ответ идеальный, но жаль что 1600 строк. Нужно будет вникнуть в концепцию.

Comment: [тыц](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/november/concurrent-affairs-the-readerwritergate-lock)

Comment: Копируете себе класс, выбрасываете все лишнее, доводите до минимализма используемых методов и готово. Думаю, на пару часов возни, не больше. Дотнетовский код, как правило избыточен, потому что заточен работать на разных платформах в разных условиях. Например рекурсия в 99% случаев не нужна, но она там есть, а штука не простая.

Comment: да и там же не 1600 строк кода, там еще процентов 20-30 комментарии